# I am planning to brew a GRUIT

Tags: alpha-acids

In the life of each home-brewer there is a moment when he decides to do something crazy (like gruit). I understand, that chances of me making a drinkable gruit are pretty low... But.. you know.

I already got a nice selection of dried leafs and flowers that are used in cooking (like making disgusting and not so much teas). And I'm trying to experiment with just boiling it as a tea (just like my grand mother used to do).

My question is...  What should I use instead of bittering  hops? Did anybody actually tried to create an alpha-acid chard for herbs other then hops?

Answer (score 1):

You could try juniper berries or possibly spruce.

The wiki article mentions several herbs that were used in making gruit.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gruit

Answer (score 0):

I read an article from the EC Kraus blog on brewing a gruit (http://www.eckraus.com/blog/gruit-ale-recipes). In addition to talking about what a gruit is and giving some intriguing recipes, the author said these were the most common flavor agents in a gruit:

myrica gale
wild rosemary
yarrow
juniper
spruce tips
birch tips
bay
nettles
marjoram
chamomile
rose hips
lavender
elder flowers
dried licorice root
fennel seed
- See more at: http://www.eckraus.com/blog/gruit-ale-recipes#sthash.CkG8dkNM.dpuf

I thought it would be interesting to brew one of these ancient beers. I'll post here after i do so with the (hopefully) tasty results.